# Rotated GLSL texture is pixelated

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glm-math

I've made a program that displays some textures depending on the given input and can rotate, resize and move the textures depending on the given input. The program works perfectly fine but when I rotate the textures the edges appear to be pixelated, like this:

[image]

Is there a way for me to smoothen out these edges?

Here are my shaders and texture classes:

texture.vs:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);

    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

texture.fs

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture sampler
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

Here is my texture.cpp:

```cpp
    Texture::Texture(int x, int y, int w, int h, int gw, int gh)
    {
        pos.TL_x = _VERTICIZE_X(x, gw);
        pos.TL_y = -_VERTICIZE_Y(y, gh);
        pos.TR_x = _VERTICIZE_X(x + w, gw);
        pos.TR_y = -_VERTICIZE_Y(y, gh);
        pos.BL_x = _VERTICIZE_X(x, gw);
        pos.BL_y = -_VERTICIZE_Y(y + h, gh);
        pos.BR_x = _VERTICIZE_X(x + w, gw);
        pos.BR_y = -_VERTICIZE_Y(y + h, gh);
    }

    void set_max_z(int z)
    {
        max_z = z;
    }

    int Texture::init(float ang_rad, float z)
    {

        shader = Shader("./src/opengl/shaders/image.vs", "./src/opengl/shaders/image.fs");

        this->angle = ang_rad;
        // build and compile our shader zprogram
        // ------------------------------------
        // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        float vertices[32] = {
            // positions            // colors           // texture coords
            pos.TR_x, pos.TR_y, _VERTICIZE_Z(z, max_z),  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // top right
            pos.BR_x, pos.BR_y, _VERTICIZE_Z(z, max_z),  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // bottom right
            pos.BL_x, pos.BL_y, _VERTICIZE_Z(z, max_z),  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom left
            pos.TL_x, pos.TL_y, _VERTICIZE_Z(z, max_z),  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f  // top left
        };

        unsigned int indices[] = {
            0, 1, 3, // first triangle
            1, 2, 3  // second triangle
        };

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // position attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        // color attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        // texture coord attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void *)(6 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

        // load and create a texture
        // -------------------------
        // texture 1
        // ----------
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        // tell opengl for each sampler to which texture unit it belongs to (only has to be done once)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        shader.use(); // don't forget to activate/use the shader before setting uniforms!
        // either set it manually like so:
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "texture"), 0);

        return 0;
    }

    void Texture::render(int w, int h, uint8_t *buffer)
    {
        // If having trouble doing multiple textures, add "+ index to Active Texture."
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

        glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0f); // make sure to initialize matrix to identity matrix first
        transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        transform = glm::rotate(transform, glm::radians(this->angle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        // get matrix's uniform location and set matrix
        shader.use();
        unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "transform");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }

    Texture::~Texture()
    {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    }

    void Texture::framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height)
    {
        // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and
        // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
```

(_VERTICIZE just calculates points)

I'm using ubuntu, GLAD, GLFW.

Comment: Looks like a typical aliasing problem. Have you enabled antialiasing?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget How do I enable that?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Are you aware of both tri-linear filtering and multi-sample anti-aliasing MSAA?  Are you looking to fix the aliasing at the edges of your geometry or in the interior of your texture?

Comment: @Wyck By the interior you mean the fragment? This only happens when I rotate so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: __Interior__: between the green and magenta bars.  __Geometry Edges__: between the cyan bar and the black of the background.  Interior aliasing is typically due to the _sampler_ filtering mode.  Edge aliasing is typically caused by the _rasterizer_ and must be addressed by either MSAA, or by expanding the geometry and creating a special fragment shader that fixes the problem, depending on suitability to your application - e.g. adding a one-pixel-wide transparent border to the texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a classic example of [Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). We can fix this by enabling [MSAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing).

GLFW has an inbuilt way of doing that. Put this before you create the window:

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); /* if effect is not strong enough, change to 8 */
```

Edit -

You have to call `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4)` in between `glfwInit` and `glfwCreateWindow`.

Also, in case OpenGL doesn't enable multisampling by default, do

```cpp
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

Comment: I have a question tho, at the end of the rendering I read the screen using `glReadPixels` to use it somewhere else, will adding `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4)` also fix the red frame?

Comment: @Turgut What red frame?

Comment: The frame I'm reading via, glReadPixels

Comment: Also sadly this didn't work. I even cranked it up to 16 but still no change.

Comment: @Turgut Hang on, do you mean with the edges inside the texture or on the edge of the texture?

Comment: The texture itself since when I'm not rotating the texture everything seems fine, this only happens when I give a rotation input higher than 0.

Comment: @Turgut Is it the edges of the texture, or the edges inside the texture? *The texture itself* is unclear.

Comment: for more clarification, in this picture do you mean the red circle or the blue circle? https://imgur.com/a/4jOIhGV

Comment: Both the edges of the texture and also the lines inside the texture.

Comment: @london_utku hmph? the lines inside the texture should be automatically fixed since the automatic value of the magnification and minification filters are `GL_LINEAR` and `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`, respectively, and OP doesn't specify any other values.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Hmm thanks for this clarification, it seems that i have not noticed the pixelated line inside the texture aswell, now I'm looking to fix both. But thanks to your comments I'm thinking that fixing the lines inside the texture will also fix the pixalation outside.

Comment: @Turgut By the way, 1. Does your driver support multisampling? 2. have you tried `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)` together with the code above?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget How can I check if multisampling is supported? Also ı've just tried  adding `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)` , nothing changed.

Comment: @Turgut `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_SAMPLES)`?

Comment: @Turgut also, does [this](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/4.advanced_opengl/11.1.anti_aliasing_msaa/anti_aliasing_msaa.cpp) code show soft edges?

Comment: By digging deeper into your suggestions I've fixed the pixelation thats outside the texture, however the pixelation inside the texture still remains. But I'm assuming digging deeper into the link you have provided might solve my problem. My only issue now is that when I try to use `glTexImage2DMultisample` visual studio says there is no such function.